# Sequence Convergence with Two Subscript

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ converges to $x_0$. For every fixed $n$, let $(b_{n,m})_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ converges to $a_n$. It is true in general that $(b_{n,n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x_0$?

I think it should be true. However, I am kind of stacked when proving it. Here is my argument: Fix an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$. There exists $N$ such that, for any $i\geq N$ we have $a_i\in U$, by convergence. On the other hand, fix $a_i\in X$ and its open neighborhood $V$, there exists some $N_{i}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $j\geq N_I$, we have $b_{i,j}\in V\cap U$. **Now, I need to take the supremum.** However, the supremum might not exist.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is false. Try to fine a counterexample with just rational numbers, writing down the sequences as an infinite matrix, with $a_n$ as rows and $b_m$ as columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.

Imagine for instance that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $b_{n,1}=b_{n,2}=...=b_{n,n}=1$, and then $\lim_{m\geq n} b_{n,m}=a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose that $x_0\neq 1$. Then $\lim_n b_{n,m}=a_n$, but $\lim_n b_{n,n}=1$.

Let us give concrete numbers. For instance, we define

$a_n=0$,

$b_{n,m}:=1$ for $m\leq n$, and

$b_{n,m}:=\frac{1}{m}$ for $m>n$.

Then $\lim_m b_{n,m}=0=a_n$, $\lim_n a_n=0$, but $\lim_n b_{n,n}=1$.